# Stretching a textbox in a Form in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone please explain to me why my textbox is not streching?? I've spent a ridiculous amount of time on this and I'm obviously missing something.

I've looked at various answers on SO and other website but to no avail. I've tried changing attributes in using `style`, but again no luck!

I found an article on SO but can't find it now, but I do have the sample that was provided: [resize example](http://jsbin.com/liyequwena/edit?html,output) and the article stated that you could simply set the `width:100%` in style, but even looking at this example is driving me nuts as both lines are stretching 100%, yet only one of them has it width set to 100%

```
@using System
@model MyCompany.Models.ApplicationFormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Application Form";
}

@*<h2>ApplicationForm</h2>*@

<div class="row">
    @*<div class="col-sm-6">*@
    <div class="well bs-component">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationForm", "Registration",
                FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Application Form</legend>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, 
                        new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, 
                        new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "",
                        new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            }
    </div>
    @*</div>*@
</div>
```

Comment: Use you browser tools to inspect the css of the element - is there a `max-width` set?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You were actually correct and I simply spotted by fluke while looking further into it in the tools. There is a default style created with an asp.net mvc 5 project where it set the width of `Input, TextArea and Select' to 280px!! Why on earth would MS do this! I've spent hours looking into it. I know I'm new to this, but it really doesn't help!! Really annoyed that it's not highlighted anywhere tbs! You might want to put your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look in Site.css

There probably you will find next lines

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```